# Prove any two nonabelian groups of order 4301 are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory

I'm tasked with proving (for homework) any two nonabelian groups of order $4301 = (11)(17)(23)$ are isomorphic. I've proved that for any nonabelian group $G$, we have $G = P_{11}N$, with $P_{11} \cap N = \{1\}$, where $P_{11} \cong \mathbb Z_{11}$ is an 11-Sylow subgroup of $G$, and $N = P_{17}P_{23}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ where $P_{17} \cong \mathbb Z_{17}$ and $P_{23} \cong \mathbb Z_{23}$ are the normal and unique 17-Sylow and 23-Sylow subgroups of $G$, where moreover these imply that $N \cong \mathbb Z_{17} \times \mathbb Z_{23} \cong \mathbb Z_{391}$ by the Chinese remainder theorem and some further computations.

I've also proved that the number of 11-Sylow subgroups must be 23 (or else $G$ is abelian, since the only other option is 1, but then this implies $P_{11}$ is normal and so we can write $G$ as a direct product of abelian normal subgroups), but I don't see how this fits in.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here, what I had in mind initially pursuing this direction was to show that I can determine $G$ up to isomorphism from how these subgroups fit together, but I don't see how to proceed.

I've read ahead in the textbook about semidirect products and automorphism groups a bit, but given that these haven't been covered in class, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to proceed (especially given that the homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{11} \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_{391})$ look really complicated, though I think this automorphism group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{16} \times \mathbb Z_{22}$ which might simplify it a bit, though the proof I had in mind for this again veers away from what we have covered in class). Anything I should try (especially if there's something I'm missing not reliant on the knowledge not covered in my class)?

Comment: Won't make it an answer due to it using semi-direct products that haven't been covered in your class, but by Theorem $4.5.1$ of the following file, case $(ii)$ (because $11$ does not divide $16 = 17-1$ but divides $22 = 23 - 1$), it would seem like there is indeed only one nonabelian group of order $4301$: http://users.hawknetwork.org/~adam/ClassifyPQR-FINAL.pdf

Comment: Have you already proved the result that there is a unique isomorphism class of nonabelian groups of order $pq$, where $p,q$ are primes with $p|(q-1)$? If so, then you could try and prove first that $G = P_{17} \times P_{11}P_{23}$.

Comment: Update (not sure what specifically to do on MSE in this case), but I proved the problem by more or less just proving all the machinery of semidirect products that I needed in the special case (which makes for a long assignment solution, but wasn't too bad), it turns out the "look-at-all-the-homomorphisms" arguments are a lot simpler than it appears at certain level since that $\mathbb Z_{16}$ isn't really contributing anything when we look at the homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost done it, just need to use one of the following lemmas:
$1$) Let $K$ be a finite group and $H$ a group of order $p$, where $p$ is a prime number. Assume that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are two homomorphisms from $H$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(K)$. If $\mathrm{Im}\psi$ and $\mathrm{Im}\phi$ are conjugate, then $K \times_\psi H \cong K \times_\phi H$.

$2$) Let $K$ be a finite group and $H$ a cyclic group. Assume that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are two monomorphisms from $H$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(K)$. If $\mathrm{Im}\psi=\mathrm{Im}\phi$, then $K \times_\psi H \cong K \times_\phi H$.

Here we have $\mathrm{Aut}(C_{391})$, which is isomorphic to $C_{16}\times C_{22}$. So image of any non-trivial homomorphism from $C_{11}$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(C_{391})$, equals the Sylow $11$-subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(C_{391})$. Hence both lemmas work here.

Comment: A version of lemma 2 is what I ended up using at the time of this question, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I’ve been more like Internet Explorer lately. Always late. :)